# Understanding hibernate documentation on bidirectional one-to-many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

As per the Hibernate documentation for [Bidirectional associations - 8.4.1. one-to-many / many-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch08.html#assoc-bidirectional-m21) has below statements:

> If you use a List, or other indexed collection, set the key column of
>   the foreign key to not null. Hibernate will manage the association
>   from the collections side to maintain the index of each element,
>   making the other side virtually inverse by setting update="false" and
>   insert="false"
>
> If the underlying foreign key column is NOT NULL, it is important that
>   you define not-null="true" on the  element of the collection
>   mapping. Do not only declare not-null="true" on a possible nested
>    element, but on the  element.

I am going through the documentation to understand Hibernate but I am not clear on above statements. I have few doubts like:

1) `If you use a List, or other indexed collection, set the key column of the foreign key to not null` -- Why should I set the foreign key to `not-null`, is this mandatory?

2) `making the other side virtually inverse by setting update="false" and insert="false"` -- When should we set `update="false" and insert="false"` and what happens if I don't set them?

Also the purpose of `insert` and `update` as per [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html) (section - 5.1.4.2. Property mapping with hbm.xml) is:

> update, insert (optional - defaults to true): specifies that the
>   mapped columns should be included in SQL UPDATE and/or INSERT
>   statements. Setting both to false allows a pure "derived" property
>   whose value is initialized from some other property that maps to the
>   same column(s), or by a trigger or other application.

So if I don't have any other property that maps to same column or trigger then why do we need to set them as `false`?

3) What it means when the doc says: `Do not only declare not-null="true" on a possible nested <column> element, but on the <key> element.`

Please help me in understanding these. Thanks in advance.