# Why the one-to-many bidirectional mapping with join table uses inner and left outer joins

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am following the Hibernate documentation for [Bidirectional one-to-many with Join tables](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch08.html#assoc-bidirectional-join-12m) between `Person` entity and `Address` entity and my mapping file is same as the one given in doc:

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <set name="addresses" 
        table="PersonAddress">
        <key column="personId"/>
        <many-to-many column="addressId"
            unique="true"
            class="Address"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <join table="PersonAddress" 
        inverse="true" 
        optional="true">
        <key column="addressId"/>
        <many-to-one name="person"
            column="personId"
            not-null="true"/>
    </join>
</class>
```

Now when I try to fetch the `Person` and the corresponding `Address's` using code:

```
List<Person> persons = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
        for (Person person : persons) {
            System.out.println(person);
            for (Address address : person.getAddresses()) {
                System.out.println(address);
            }
        }
```

When the line `person.getAddresses()` is run then the query generated by hibernate is :

```
Hibernate: select addresses0_.personId as personId2_1_0_, addresses0_.addressId as addressId1_2_0_, address1_.addressId as addressId1_0_1_, address1_1_.personId as personId2_2_1_ 
from PersonAddress addresses0_ 
inner join ADDRESS address1_    // INNER JOIN between PersonAddress & Address
on addresses0_.addressId=address1_.addressId 
left outer join PersonAddress address1_1_ // Now LEFT OUTER JOIN with PersonAddress
on address1_.addressId=address1_1_.addressId 
where addresses0_.personId=?
```

If we can get the data using only single `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between `PersonAddress` & `Address` then why Hibernate uses first and `INNER JOIN` then a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`? Can some please help me in understanding this.

Comment: I would suggest, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16827671/1679310). The point is that 8.5.1 mapping is really very very bad. Forget that. And because I would not recommend the many-to-many - try to think about the mapping with explicitly mapped pairing table. That will support better querying later... just suggestion ;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler, Thanks Radim, I will go through it. If possible can you please tell me answer for my query.

Comment: What's the point of `optional="true"`?

Comment: @JimmyT., I am just following the docs and copied the same mapping given in docs, I am also not sure when we need to use that `optional` attribute.